# How do you save a large amount of data using SAGE?

Tags: sage

I'm trying to save a 'big' rational matrix in SAGE, but I'm running into problems. After computing my matrix A, which has size 5 x 10,000 and each entry contains rational numbers in fraction form with total number of digits for numerator and denominator more than 10 pages, I run the following command:

save(A, DATA + 'A'). 
This gives me the following error message:

Traceback(most recent call last): 
... 
RuntimeError: Segmentation fault.
I tried the same save command with a 'smaller' matrix and that worked fine. I should also note that I'm using a laptop with a 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor, Windows 8, i7 CPU @ 2.40 GHz and 8 GB RAM. I'm running SAGE on a virtual machine to which I allocated 5237 MB. Let me know if you need further information. My questions are:

Why can't I save my matrix? Why do I get the above error message? What does it mean?

How can I save my matrix A using this command? Is there any other way I can save it?

I have asked these same questions in another forum which specifically deals with SAGE, but I'm not getting an answer there. I have also spent a lot of time searching online about this question, but haven't seen anyone with this same problem.

Comment: I am not familiar with SAGE so excuse me if this is an uninformed answer, but when you say "total number of digits... more than 10 pages" what do the pages refer to?  Can you estimate this in actual digits?

Comment: This is a very good question actually. I will get back to you with the exact number of digits. It will just take a couple of days though. Thank you for asking.

Comment: @GodricSeer global_height() method in SAGE outputs max{log(n), log(d)} where n and d are the numerator and denominator respectively in reduced form of our rational number input. Using this method, I got an output of about 75000.  So "total number of digits... more than 10 pages" means around 75000 digits for the numerator and 75000 digits for the denominator of only one of my entries in the matrix.

Comment: That comes out to about 3GB of memory just to hold the numerators and denominators.  Each number likely has some small overhead as well.  By the time the OS and virtual machine take their bits of the memory, you are likely cutting it close.  I am not sure what the save command does that runs you over the limit.  My guess is that it copies what you want to save, then saves it.  This would explain the row saving failing as well, but this is all just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't I save my matrix? Why do I get the above error message? What does it mean?

Most likely is that it means you ran out of memory.  The underlying large integer libraries sometimes segfault instead of giving more useful out of memory errors.

You might try saving each row of the matrix individually, e.g., row 0 is A[0], so try

```
save(A[0], DATA + 'A0')
```

If this works, you could load each row and make the matrix from the rows.

-- william

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried to save row by row, but I ran into the same problem. Is there a way to allocate more memory, or should I try a better computer?